# C Language Operators

Tags: c, operators, ternary-operator, operator-precedence, conditional-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() 
{

    int a=-1?2:5 + 8?4:5;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of above program is 2. But why ? Please explain

Comment: **Don't** write code like that, please.

Comment: You can try dissecting the code into single expressions and print them out

Comment: You should explain why you cannot explain this code.

Comment: Why do you think it might be something other than `2`?  Explain your reasoning, and then we can help you understand where you went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Write human-readable and understandable code. (*Atleast, try to...*)

```
 int a=-1?2:5 + 8?4:5;
```

is the same as

```
int a = (-1) ? 2 : ( 5 + ( 8 ? 4 : 5) );
```

**<sup>Reference: [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)</sup>**

Now, let's compare that with the ternary operator condition, as mentioned in `C11`, chapter §6.5.15,

> The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
>   evaluation of the second or third operand **(whichever is evaluated)**. The second operand
>   is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated),

So, in your case,

- First operand is unequal to zero
- So, it evaluates the second operand and the result, the value of the operand, is returned and stored into the LHS variable of assignment operator.

Comment: I object to the second form being dubbed "human-readable and understandable"

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, better now? Can't do more than that.

Comment: Not really. My objection is in general to the application of "human-readable and understandable" to any code that uses the ternary operator like that :)

Comment: @StoryTeller :) I know, see my comment under the question.

Answer (score 3):

The statement :

```
int a=-1?2:5 + 8?4:5;
```

or better written with parentheses :

```
int a = (-1) ? 2 : ( 5 + 8?4:5);
```

which in turn means :

```
if (-1)
    a = 2;
else {
    if (8)
        a = 9; //5+4
    else
        a = 10; //5+5
}
```

Any condition different than `0` is evaluated as `true`. So the condition `if(-1)` is different than `0`, therefore `true`. Thus, the `if` block will be executed and `a` will get value `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `a ? b : c` evaluates to `b` if `a` is non-zero, and in your code `a` (`-1`) is non-zero and `b` is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look it step by step process,

int a=-1?2:5 + 8?4:5;

```
int a = (-1) ? 2 : ( 5 + 8?4:5);
```

for ternary operator  (condition) ? return true: return false;

```
0 = False 
Other than 0 = true
```

Hence -1 = true

```
  int a = (true) ? 2 : ( 5 + 8?4:5);
  int a = 2;
```

Comment: This is C, and here, in this case `true` and `false` has actually defined values, they are 1 and 0, here, respectively.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The macros `true` and `false` are part of the C standard library, not part of the language.  Their _integer constant_  values of 1 and 0 are defined when `<stdbool.h>` is read.  This answer apparently uses "true", "false" in a logic sense and not a C Library keyword sense.

Comment: @chux agree, just thought of putting a comment to get exactly this point clarified, thanks for completing the comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

On a general note: the format:

```
x = a ? b : c;
```

Means:

```
if (a) // always results in true unless a = 0
    x = b;
else
   x = c;
```

Now, your statement when parenthesized:

```
int a = (-1) ? 2 : ( 5 + ( 8 ? 4 : 5) );
```

is merely a shortened if-else nested group of statements. When expanded, it looks something like:

```
if (-1) // since it is not zero, this is true
    a = 2;

else // since the if-block is true, this is ignored by the compiler
{
    if (8)
        a = 5 + 4; // computes to 9
    else
        a = 5 + 5; // computes to 10
}
```

Hence, since the first if-statement is true, the compiler stores 2 in variable `a`.

As an aside, you should refrain from writing code that is hard to read. Even though your statement was shorter than writing an entire if-block, reading the if-else nested block is way easier to understand than reading your statement.